# Is this console message high priority? prefs: blah\userpref.blend Traceback (most recent call last): File blah addon_utils.py

Tags: error, versions

Here is the full message in Console

Read prefs: C:\Users\secret\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
mod = **import**(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oscurart_tools'

Is this situation likely to cause Blender to crash?
Blender is crashing very often in the recent past two weeks.

---

bpy.app.version_string
'3.0.0'

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1466]

Comment: as far as I know, no module named... errors just means blender can't find the add-on (at least anytime I have noticed anyhow). Maybe oscurant has been moved?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, nothing to be concerned about.

Oscurart tools was [removed from Blender distribution](https://blenderartists.org/t/oscurart-tools-not-included-in-2-91/1267891) by the original author.  Apparently upgrades didn't necessarily notice that and you may have a preferences file where it is listed.  If you're not using it, it's not an issue, and if you are, the Blender Artists thread describes where to get it.

If you reload add-ons, you will sometimes discover messages like this.  The majority of them are harmless.  The ones that will cause you problems probably already have and you've noticed and done something about it.